# Separate strings by word to a separate line in Python

Tags: python, string, file

I have a line in my textfile like the line below:

```
hi   everyone  this is good
the weather is good     yes
```

I want to write each string in one line like this:

```
  hi
  everyone
  this
```

What should i do? I dont know the number of spaces between each string.

Thank you

I used this method but it didn´t work

```
text_file = open("1.txt","r")
for line in text_file :
    lline = list(line)
    lline.replace(" ", "")
    line1 = lline.join()
    file.write(line1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the lines by whitespaces and flatten the list:

```
lines = ['hi there', 'how    are you   today']
tokens = [token for line in lines for token in line.split()]
# tokens: ['hi', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today']
```

When reading from file the code should be:

```
with open('1.txt', 'rt') as text_file:
    tokens = [token for line in text_file for token in line.split()]
    target_file.write('\n'.join(tokens))
```

**Edit** thanks to [officialaimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6656473/officialaimm)'s comment the example was simplified from `re.split(r'\s+', line)` to `line.split()`.

Comment: Why not use the split in string class itself?? Null argumented `split` will do the work I guess.

Comment: @officialaimm, you're correct, that would be better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use split function.

like:

```
 text_file = open("1.txt","r").read()
 for i in text_file.strip().split('\n'):
    [print(j) for j in i.split()]
----
hi
everyone
this
is
good
the
weather
is
good
yes
```

it'll print the result.

Comment: it work but if my string was other language what should i do

Comment: what do you mean the other language?

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.sub`:

```
In [227]: import re

In [228]: line = '''hi   everyone  this is good
     ...:   the weather is good     yes'''

In [233]: print(re.sub('\s+', '\n', line, re.M | re.DOTALL))
hi
everyone
this
is
good
the
weather
is
good
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just make sure file is a file connection open for writing.

```
text_file = open("1.txt","r")
for line in text_file :
    lline = line.split()
    line1 = '\n'.join(lline)
    file.write(line1)
```